# How to use $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to write a new URL and not infinitely-loop?

Tags: php

I have a php page and want to write a link that is based on the current URL.  Like so:

```
$alias = substr(strrchr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/"), 1);

print '<a href="'.$alias.'&sort=name">Sort by Name</a>';
```

On the page http://domain.com/listings , the link is written to http://domain.com/listings&sort=name , which works perfectly.

But then once I am on the page http://domain.com/listings&sort=name, the link on the page is written to http://domain.com/listings&sort=name&sort=name.  Additionally, if I click one of the other sorting links I will end up with http://domain.com/listings&sort=name&sort=comments .

That is dorky.  Is there a better way to generate my link?  Or should I do something to clean $alias before I reuse it?  Complication:  There are some variables (like `&category=34` and `&title=spa`) that I *don't* want to remove from the URL, so I can't just clean it back to `/listings`.

(I am using Drupal, if there are secret variables built in there that would be cool too.)

Answer (score 1):

One common strategy is to do something like:

```
http_build_query(array_merge($_GET, array("sort" => "name")))
```

to calculate the new query string.

Comment: Ooh, interesting.  This doesn't quite work out of the box (it generates the url as "domain.com/q=listings&sort=name" -- some weird hybrid of Drupal's plain URL code and clean URL code and my own additional parameter) but definitely worth looking into!